# How do I get the square to continually move across the screen as a direction key is held down?

Tags: python, macos, boolean, pygame

When I run this code on a Windows pc the square continues to move across the screen in the appropriate direction as I hold down the respective key, but when I run it on raspberry pi or mac it jumps 5 pixels then stops. How can I get it to move across the screen When I hold down the respective key?

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
x = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((x, x))
pygame.display.set_caption('This is printed on the top of the tab or window!')

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

moveSpeed = 5

moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveDown = False
moveUp = False

player = pygame.Rect(150, 150, 50, 50)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, player)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moveDown = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moveUp = False
        if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
            player.left -= moveSpeed
        if moveRight and player.right < x:
            player.right += moveSpeed
        if moveDown and player.bottom < x:
            player.bottom += moveSpeed
        if moveUp and player.top > 0:
            player.top -= moveSpeed
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, player)
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(0.02)
```

Comment: Maybe one of the solutions described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494726/how-to-use-pygame-keydown/25501071#25501071) SO answer may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by indenting the lines...

```
    if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
        player.left -= moveSpeed
    if moveRight and player.right < x:
        player.right += moveSpeed
    if moveDown and player.bottom < x:
        player.bottom += moveSpeed
    if moveUp and player.top > 0:
        player.top -= moveSpeed
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, player)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

... Back four spaces. Also, i learned, for amateur questions like these, certain sub-reddits like  /r/learpython is a great place to get answers.