# Pygame - Smoother Movement

Tags: python, pygame

I have added an Object/Image on the `main_screen`, the object is called `cancer_cell`. 
What I'm trying to do here is that I want the object move smoothly. I have to repeatedle press on the arrow keys to keep it moving. 
How do I make it move `while` arrow keys are pressed ?

here's the code:

```
exitgame = False
cellpos_x = 0
cellpos_y = cancer_cell.get_rect().height*2
while not exitgame:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exitgame = True
            quitgame()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                cellpos_x -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                cellpos_x += 10


    gameplay_bg = pygame.image.load("/Users/wolf/Desktop/python/img/gameplay_bg.png").convert()
    main_screen.fill(white)
    main_screen.blit(gameplay_bg, [0,0])
    main_screen.blit(cancer_cell, [cellpos_x, cellpos_y])
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)
```

someone told me to try the solution at [How to use pygame.KEYDOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494726/how-to-use-pygame-keydown):
but that didn't work either. Or maybe i did it wrong:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        cellpos_x -= 10
    if key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        cellpos_x += 10
```

Comment: You might want to clarify on what you're asking.

Comment: So i have this object/image on the `main_screen`, which is called `cancer_cell`, When i move with arrow keys, I have to repeatedle press, otherwise it wont move if I hold the key down.

Comment: Please edit the question instead of commenting.

Comment: And the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494726/how-to-use-pygame-keydown) wasn't really too difficult to find.

Comment: I tried that solution before, won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I have solved the problem by just unindenting this part from the `FOR` loop
    while not exitgame:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exitgame = True
            quitgame()

    key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        cellpos_x -= 10
    if key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        cellpos_x += 10
```

Comment: Basically what is going on here is that the event loop only applies the event effect once. i.e `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: do stuff` means that Pygame will detect that you pressed the left arrow key, do whatever you ask it ONCE, and then wait for you to release the key and press it back again before doing the effect again. This is why you had to keep pressing the key. Using pygame.key.get_pressed() however means that pygame will continuously check this value without you having to release the key. This is an important difference.

Comment: Keep this in mind if for things like, having a sprite following the mouse position continuously (you'd probably want `pygame.mouse_getpos()` outside the event loop), whereas if you want to implement a button you probably want the effect to occur only once per click on the button (probably better to use a condition from the event loop in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I see you've solved the indentation issue, here's another version of your example:

```
import pygame

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, img_path):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(img_path)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = self.image.get_rect().height*2

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= dist

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
size = width, height = 1024, 768
speed = [2, 2]
white = 1, 1, 1
main_screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
gameplay_bg = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")
cancer_cell = Player("player.jpg")
running = False

while not running:
    event = pygame.event.poll()

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = True

    main_screen.fill(white)
    main_screen.blit(gameplay_bg, [0, 0])

    cancer_cell.handle_keys()
    cancer_cell.draw(main_screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(50)
    pygame.display.set_caption("fps: " + str(clock.get_fps()))
```

You need to adjust the paths of the images ("background.jpg", "player.jpg"), with this version you're not loading over and over your sprite in the game event loop and the Player movement will be smooth.