# Create hotkeys to stop python function

Tags: python

I make a auto game with python, after run python function, the mouse and keyboard actions loop infinity. As i know, if want to stop python function we use `Ctrl+C` to make keyboard interupt. But, in this case it cannot stop. So have anyway can listen hotkey from keyboard like `Ctrl+Shift+Alt` like

```
while(keyboard_listen == false):
    mystuff()
```

to listen keyboard hotkey event to make the python function stop?

Comment: I would suggest to look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494726/how-to-use-pygame-keydown

Comment: have anyway without use pygame library?