# How to get if a key is pressed pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to check if a key is pressed in pygame. I do not mean by using the `KEYDOWN` or `KEYUP` methods. The thing is, if I only check for those methods, I only get feedback (I don't know any other way to phrase it) **AS** the key is pressed. I do not get feedback in between key press and release. I want to get if the key is currently down.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use pygame.KEYDOWN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494726/how-to-use-pygame-keydown)

Comment: You can assume that the key is being held down between the `keydown` and `keyup` events.

Answer (score 2):

The current state of the keys can be get by [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed).

Get the sate of the keys `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` and evaluate if the <kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>DOWN</kbd> is pressed by `if keys[pygame.K_UP]:` respectively `if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:`, continuously in the main application loop:

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        # [...]
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        # [...]
```

Note, the states which are returned by `pygame.key.get_pressed()` are updated when the events are handled by [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).

Comment: Thank you. I think I might have learned this somewhere but forgot.