# How do I move elements of a matrix in python?

Tags: python, matrix, pygame

I want to move object 1 with the keyboard, using events from pygame, like: pygame.key.get_pressed(). But I don't know how to put it on my code.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
tela = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 560))
jogo = True

class Tabuleiro:
    def __init__(self, tela, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tela = tela
        self.maze = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

    def show(self):
        for col in range(20):
            for lin in range(11):
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 1:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 255, 255), rect=[self.x + col * 49, self.y + lin * 49, 49, 49])
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 2:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 255, 0), rect=[self.x + col * 30, self.y + lin * 30, 25, 25])
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 3:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 0, 0), rect=[self.x + col * 50, self.y + lin * 50, 25, 25])


maze = tabuleiro.Tabuleiro(tela, 10, 10)

while jogo:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            jogo = False

    tela.fill(0)
    maze.show()
    pygame.display.update()
```

And I don't know how to use collide functions as well, this code is for a Pac-Man game I have to do as a school homework. I'm glad if i could get some tips about it as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fix the representation of the maze. The top left of eah cell is `self.x + col * 50, self.y + lin * 50`:

```py
class Tabuleiro:
    # [...]

    def show(self):
        for col in range(20):
            for lin in range(11):
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 1:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 255, 255), rect=[self.x + col * 50, self.y + lin * 50, 50, 50])
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 2:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 255, 0), rect=[self.x + col * 50 + 12, self.y + lin * 50 + 12, 25, 25])
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 3:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 0, 0), rect=[self.x + col * 50 + 12, self.y + lin * 50 + 12, 25, 25])
```

You need to add some methods to the `Tabuleiro` class. Add a method that can find a specific `number` in the grid:

```py
class Tabuleiro:
    # [...]

    def findFirst(self, number):
        for row, rowlist in enumerate(self.maze):
            for col, cell in enumerate(rowlist):
                if cell == number:
                    return row, col
        return None, None
```

Add a method that test if a row index (`row`) and column index (`col`) is valid:

```py
class Tabuleiro:
    # [...]

    def testIndex(self, row, col):
        if row == None or col == None:
            return False
        if 0 <= row < len(self.maze) and 0 <= col < len(self.maze[row]):
            return True
        return False
```

Add a method to test whether the content of a cell is a specific `number`:

```py
class Tabuleiro:
    # [...]

    def isFieldEqual(self, row, col, number):
        if self.testIndex(row, col):
            return self.maze[row][col] == number
        return False
```

Add a method that swaps the contents of 2 cells:

```py
class Tabuleiro:
    # [...]

    def swapFileds(self, row1, col1, row2, col2):
        if self.testIndex(row1, col1) and self.testIndex(row2, col2):
            self.maze[row1][col1], self.maze[row2][col2] = self.maze[row2][col2], self.maze[row1][col1]
```

There are several methods of detecting keys pressed in Pygame. See [How to get if a key is pressed pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59830738/how-to-get-if-a-key-is-pressed-pygame/59831073#59831073).

For example, use the `KEYDOWN event. Whenever you want to move an object, you need to test that the cell you want to move to is empty (0). When moving, only the contents of the cells are swapped:

```py
while jogo:

    row, col = maze.findFirst(2)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            jogo = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row, col-1, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row, col-1, row, col)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row, col+1, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row, col+1, row, col)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row-1, col, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row, col, row-1, col)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row+1, col, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row+1, col, row, col)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
tela = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 560))
jogo = True

class Tabuleiro:
    def __init__(self, tela, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tela = tela
        self.maze = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

    def show(self):
        for col in range(20):
            for lin in range(11):
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 1:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 255, 255), rect=[self.x + col * 50, self.y + lin * 50, 50, 50])
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 2:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 255, 0), rect=[self.x + col * 50 + 12, self.y + lin * 50 + 12, 25, 25])
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 3:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 0, 0), rect=[self.x + col * 50 + 12, self.y + lin * 50 + 12, 25, 25])

    def findFirst(self, number):
        for row, rowlist in enumerate(self.maze):
            for col, cell in enumerate(rowlist):
                if cell == number:
                    return row, col
        return None, None

    def testIndex(self, row, col):
        if row == None or col == None:
            return False
        if 0 <= row < len(self.maze) and 0 <= col < len(self.maze[row]):
            return True
        return False

    def isFieldEqual(self, row, col, number):
        if self.testIndex(row, col):
            return self.maze[row][col] == number
        return False 
    
    def swapFileds(self, row1, col1, row2, col2):
        if self.testIndex(row1, col1) and self.testIndex(row2, col2):
            self.maze[row1][col1], self.maze[row2][col2] = self.maze[row2][col2], self.maze[row1][col1]


maze = Tabuleiro(tela, 10, 10)

while jogo:

    row, col = maze.findFirst(2)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            jogo = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row, col-1, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row, col-1, row, col)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row, col+1, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row, col+1, row, col)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row-1, col, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row, col, row-1, col)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row+1, col, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row+1, col, row, col)

    tela.fill(0)
    maze.show()
    pygame.display.update()
```